# Anyway to verify updates were installed?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

I have vmware workstation installed and there's a bug in the installer that causes it to not use LSB headers for the scripts on Debian (debian run level scripts require lsb headers). This means that anytime a runlevel script is configured, insserv/update-rc fails because the vmware scripts don't have the lsb headers.

I installed the 6.02 update from Debian which updates a lot of packages. After installing, it started processing the triggers. However, because of vmware, the triggers failed and one of the packages also failed (pretty sure it was all because of vmware).

I manually fixed the vmware scripts by adding insserv overrides and ran aptitude update and aptitude safe-upgrade again. This time it ran some triggers and looks like there were no errors.

I restarted and ran the aptitude update and safe-upgrade again and it showed there were no updates to install.

Is there a way to verify that all the updates from the 6.02 update was installed and configure correctly? Is there a way to rerun those triggers OR maybe even rerun the 6.02 update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it's no big deal if insserv/update-rc fails. All it means is that it will use the old way of starting/stopping services as used in lenny and before. As far as I know the biggest advantage of the "new way" is that init scripts can start and stop asynchronously. I have had this fail on many servers and decided not to waste time investigating since it's no big deal.

You can be sure that if you run commands such as "apt-get update/upgrade/dist-upgrade" (or aptitude) and it reports the system to be up to date that it IS up to date. Provided your sources.list file has the right repositories configured.